# Under the discrete metric $f$ is continuous, open and closed, proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

> If $d_x$ is the discrete metric in $X$. Prove that for any function $f:(X,d_X)\to(Y,\tau_y)$ is continuous, open and closed.

For example if we consider the metric $d_X(x,y)=$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
   1 &\text{if} & x\neq y \\
     0 &\text{if} & x= y \\
  \end{array}
\right.$ for $x,y\in X$.

$A\in \tau_y$, $f^{-1}(A)=C\in X$. I want to prove $C$ is open.

**Question:**

How can I prove the claim? How is there an open interval with the discrete metric? $B(a,r)=\{x\in X:d(a,x)<r\}$, for $r>0$. How can $B(a,r)$ be an open ball on $(X,d_x)$ according to the discrete metric?

Comment: What do you mean when you write $A\in\tau_y$, $f^{-1}(A)=1$?

Comment: What is $(T,\tau_y)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I have just corrected the error.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to prove because, although the "continuous" part of the question is correct, the "open" and "closed" parts are not in general true.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Sorry, I have just corrected the error.

Comment: About "How is there an open interval ...?": Why do you expect the notion of "interval" to make sense in this context? Do you have a definition of "interval" in general metric spaces?

Comment: Inspecting the definition of open balls  and the definition of the metric, it follows that $B(a,r)$ is $\{a\}$ if $r\leq1$ and all of $X$ if $r>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $C$ is open, because, under the discrete topology, *every* set is open (and closed, too).

However, you can't prove that $f$ is open and closed, because, in general, that is not true.

Comment: If we have a ball in $(X,d_x)$, with the discrete metric and we pick a open ball $B(c,r)=\{x\in X:d_x(x,c)=1\}$. How can I prove that every set is open and closed under the discrete topology? Thanks for the answers insofar.

Comment: @PedroGomes I don't understand your first sentence. Anyway, If $A\subset X$, then for each $a\in A$, $B(a,1)=\{a\}\subset A$. Therefore, $A$ is open. The same argument applies to $X\setminus A$. Therefore, $A$ is closed.